# How to add Field Help in SuiteScript 2.0 Suitelet forms?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I want to add field Help to a Suitelet Field created in SuiteScript 2.0 using forms

[This is what is needed in SuiteScript 2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeJ8t.png)

```
var captureBillingField = form.addField({
    id: 'custpage_rent_setup_capture_billing',
    type: serverWidget.FieldType.CHECKBOX,
    label: 'CAPTURE BILLING AUTOMATED',
    container: 'fieldgroupcapture'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setHelpText](https://system.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4335195721.html) method on the field object returned by [addField](https://system.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4337905245.html) as below

```
var captureBillingField = form.addField({
    id: 'custpage_rent_setup_capture_billing',
    type: serverWidget.FieldType.CHECKBOX,
    label: 'CAPTURE BILLING AUTOMATED',
    container: 'fieldgroupcapture'
})
    .setHelpText({
        help: SOME-HELP-TEXT
    });
```

**Note:** *setHelpText* returns field object.